# Product URL issue when same product assigned in multiple category

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, url, product-urls, ee-1.14.2.4

I need to know how exactly Magento creates URLs when the same product is added into multiple category and when include category path in product URL is set to "YES". Will it create two separate URLs for the same product?

In my case if product1 assigned into category A and Category B 
and if I open this product1 from category B, it shows product URL like 
`www.site.com/category-b/product1.html`, and when I open the same product from category A it is still show the same old URL `www.site.com/category-b/product1.html`.

Is this the default Magento URL behavior? How much this will effect on SEO?

In which case the product will use URL from category A i.e `www.site.com/category-a/product1.html`?

I am using Magento 1.14.2.4.

Comment: Yes this the default Magento URL behavior

Comment: " In which case the product will use URL from category A i.e www,site.com/category-a/product1.html" from where user is browsing that product.i.e from which category

Comment: Its not like that , even if I visit the product from category A , it is still showing the product url www.site.com/category-b/product1.html

Comment: i am not sure about 1.14.2.4. may be it is bug but default behavior is like that. you can browse that product from 3 url 
1.www.site.com/category-a/product1.html
2.www.site.com/category-b/product1.html 
3.www.site.com/product1.html